# Automatic cluster setup and app deployment on GCE Kubernetes

Tags: automation, kubernetes, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, declarative

We are looking for a solid, declarative (yaml), based proceedure to automate the setup of our Kubernetes cluster and application deployments on Google Container Engine.

As our last resort in a serious failure we want to be able to:

- Create a new GCE cluster
- Execute all our deployments to their latest versions
- Execute all the steps in the correct order

What are the solutions people are currently using. Doing this manually takes us about an hour and is error prone. Really it could take 15-20 mins if automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Google Cloud Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/). It "automates the creation and management of your Google Cloud Platform resources for you" meaning that it can create a Google Container Engine cluster as well as create your deployments.

Looking through the [GKE deployment manager example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/gke) should help get you started.